# Why is 'c' minimized in sklearns logistic regression implementation?

Tags: regression, logistic, scikit-learn

I understood how the logistic model works and what it represents (log-odds). All the information on how the parameters are fit only evolved around the statistical way of maximizing the log-likelihood. In machine learning, at least how I understood it, the problem is usually tackled from the other side. Meaning we measure how 'wrong' the model is by a loss function. The default objective in sklearns implementation is the log-loss with l2 regularization:

$\min_{\mathbf{w},c} \frac{1}{2}\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{w}+C\sum_{i=1}^n \ln(1+e^{-y_i(\mathbf{x_i}^T\mathbf{w}+c)}).$

I have troble understanding where the small *c* variable stems from and why it is minimized. Can someone please explain?

Best, Jonas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$c$ is the intercept, [often](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression#Logistic_model) denoted $\beta_0$.
It is not minimized but the loss function is minimized with $\mathbf{w}$ and $c$ as parameters.

Comment: Yes thank you, I just found out by looking through the associated papers and how they defined the notation.I was just confused because I personally used the notation where the intercept is combined into the **w**.

Comment: Yes it is a bit non-standard, I guess it is to match the notation with the `X` input in the API, which is easier for users as it does not require adding a column of ones beforehand.